# Clarifying Function Notation and Determining Domain Transformation: f(x) and f(2x+3)

Tags: functions

I'm looking to deepen my understanding of function notation and its implications in mathematical transformations. While I comprehend the concept of f(x) denoting a function with 'x' as the input variable, I'm seeking clarification regarding the disparity between f(x) and f(2x+3), particularly concerning the role of 'x' in each representation.

Could someone elucidate the core distinction between 'x' in f(x) and 'x' in f(2x+3)? How does the behavior of the function differ when its input involves a composite expression like 2x+3 instead of a solitary 'x'? Some concrete examples illustrating this discrepancy would greatly aid my comprehension.

Lastly, considering a scenario where f(x) is defined over the interval [0,1], I'm interested in determining the domain of the transformed function f(2x+3). How does the interval [0,1] for 'x' translate when applying the transformation 2x+3 to the function?

I appreciate your assistance and insights. Thank you!

Comment: The case of f(2x+3) is distinct from f(x) because f(2x+3) is really a composition of two functions. Let g(x) = 2x + 3, then f(g(x)) is a composition of two functions. the domain of f, would be the range of g(x). If g(x) has it's domain be the interval [0,1], then its  range would be [3,6]. Which, would be the domain of f(g(x)), assuming there aren't any additional restrictions on the domain, based in how f is defined